# Etymology of the phrase "Dependency injection" in computer science

Tags: meaning, etymology, terminology, computing

It's my understanding that this used to be simply referred to as "reference passing" but later became formalized into a pattern that implemented a design principle and acquired the new name.  Can you shed some light on the meaning and history?

Comment: Could this help? 
***History of Dependency Injection (DI)*** : 
https://yauritux.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/history-of-dependency-injection-di/

Comment: That's a useful explanation of meaning but it doesn't tell me much in the way of history.  Who coined the term for example.  @Josh61

Comment: ***Inversion of control is not a new term in computer science. Martin Fowler traces the etymology of the phrase back to 1988***. Dependency injection is a specific type of IoC using contextualized lookup.  The use of a service locator is considered to be the same design pattern. In an article by Loek Bergman, it is presented as an architectural principle. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control

Comment: Martin Fowler has released a paper on the Dependency Injection pattern. ***This is his rebranding of the Inversion of Control that we hear so much about in the recent wave of lightweight frameworks.*** http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=23358

Comment: It looks like the expression *dependency injection was coined by Martin Fowler: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection - 
 ***Martin Fowler's original article that introduced the term Dependency Injection  ...***

Comment: @Josh61 Seems like you have enough references for a good answer there.

Comment: Since 1985, all new computer buzzwords have been produced by a buzzword sweat shop in Chengdu China.

Answer (score 2):

It was almost certainly Martin Fowler who coined the term, and other responders have pointed to its first use in publication.

The reason for the choice of term appears to be that the concept of 'injection' was relatively new at the time.  Other ways of getting a dependency in a class, such as inline instantiation, are essentially 'creation within', rather than 'insertion from the outside', which is what was new about this concept in the history of best practices for the writing of maintainable code - hence Fowler's 'injection'.

EDIT

This article, written in 2004, is the earliest known usage of the phrase: http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection

The concept itself, previously known as the 'Dependency Inversion Principle', was first created by Robert C. Martin, in the mid-90's:
http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/dip.pdf

Comment: Hi, Sam Burns, and welcome to English Language & Usage. I realize that you may have omitted links to any references connecting Martin Fowler to the term "dependency injunction" in part because Josh61 cites three such references to Fowler in comments beneath the poster's question. However, at this site we especially value self-contained answers, and yours would be stronger and more complete if you linked to one or more references that bring together Fowler and the term in question. Please consider doing so.